# Why does runif() have less unique values than rnorm()?

Tags: r, random

If you run code like:

```
length(unique(runif(10000000)))
length(unique(rnorm(10000000)))
```

you'll see that only about 99.8% of runif values are unique, but 100% of rnorm values are. I thought this might be because of the constrained range, but upping the range to (0, 100000) for runif doesn't change the result. Continuous distributions should have probability of repeats =0, and I know in floating-point precision that's not the case, but I'm curious why we don't see fairly close to the same number of repeats between the two.

Comment: IF your read the op: *but upping the range to (0, 100000) for runif doesn't change the result*

Comment: Well, one could argue that 99.8% IS fairly close..

Comment: @RLava I would not argue so.

Comment: kind of a joke..

Comment: @RLave if you think about it in terms of probability of any two numbers colliding, the probabilites between runif and rnorm would have to be orders of magnitude different to produces these results.

Comment: What about the different support of the distributions? Just a thought, I was going to use it as an anwer but I'm not so sure. The uniform as a limit in the x values, the normal doesn't, so in my logic you have a "better chance" to obtain different values.

Comment: @Ryan I get the same results as op using uniqueN().

Comment: I don't know if I can make myself more clear in just the space of a comment..

Comment: @RLave shouldn't it be solved by `(uniqueN(runif(10000000, min = .Machine$double.xmin, max = .Machine$double.xmax)))`

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the function used under the hood? Still mine was just a huch

Answer (score 3):

This is due primarily to the properties of the default PRNG (the fact that `runif` has a smaller range than `rnorm` and therefore a smaller number of representable values may also have a similar effect at some point even if the RNG doesn't). It is discussed somewhat obliquely in `?Random`:

> Do not rely on randomness of low-order bits from RNGs. Most of the
>   supplied uniform generators return 32-bit integer values that are
>   converted to doubles, so they take at most 2^32 distinct values and
>   long runs will return duplicated values (Wichmann-Hill is the
>   exception, and all give at least 30 varying bits.)

With the example:

```
sum(duplicated(runif(1e6))) # around 110 for default generator
## and we would expect about almost sure duplicates beyond about
qbirthday(1 - 1e-6, classes = 2e9) # 235,000
```

Changing to the Wichmann-Hill generator indeed reduces the chance of duplicates:

```
RNGkind("Wich")  
sum(duplicated(runif(1e6)))
[1] 0
sum(duplicated(runif(1e8)))
[1] 0
```

Comment: It is nice to see confirmation that the phenomenon disappears when you switch to Wichmann-Hill.

Comment: I like this answer and it points out some good things, but it doesn't really answer the main question. If I'm not using Wichmann-Hill, shouldn't both methods be using the default? And if I'm using the default shouldn't both methods have approximately the same amount of repeats?

Comment: @jntrcs The answer states that `runif` under the default generators has a limited level of randomness. `rnorm` isn't documented to have the same limitation .

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Random.html) for random number generations says:

> Do not rely on randomness of low-order bits from RNGs. Most of the
>   supplied uniform generators return 32-bit integer values that are
>   converted to doubles, so they take at most 2^32 distinct values and
>   long runs will return duplicated values (Wichmann-Hill is the
>   exception, and all give at least 30 varying bits.)

By the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) you would expect to see repeated values in a set of more than roughly 2^16 values, and 10000000 > 2^16. I haven't found anything directly in the documentation about how many distinct values `rnorm` will return, but it is presumably larger than 2^32. It is interesting to note that `set.seed` has different parameters `kind` which determines the uniform generator and `normal.kind` which determines the normal generator, so the latter is not a simple transformation of the former.